# Retrieve emails with campaign ID in Mailgun

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I would like to get campaign stats such as a clicked count, opened count etc through Mailgun. This is explained at "Basic Examples" in https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-campaigns.html#basic-examples.

I sent a test email with PHP and codeigniter.
I checked the sent email in Mailgun GUI page and saw headers were added like this (which I think correct):

```
X-Mailgun-Tag: 3511 (note: I also added tag for testing)
X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id: test-campaign-3511
```

Now, if I type "test-campaign-3511" in the search box in Mailgun GUI, it will not find any email. However, it will retrieve this test email correctly with the search text "3511". So, it works with tag, but not campaign ID.

What I need eventually is getting campaign stats through PHP, so I tried this:

```
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/campaigns/test-campaign-3511");
```

Result is

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Http\Client\Exception\HttpException
>
> Message: Client error: `GET https://api.mailgun.net/v2/(my
>   domain)/campaigns/test-campaign-3511` resulted in a `404 Not Found`
>   response: { "message": "Campaign not found" }

Next I tried without campaign ID:

```
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/campaigns");
```

Result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [http_response_body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                )

            [total_count] => 0
        )

    [http_response_code] => 200
)
```

It looks like I am failing to create campaign there. Is there anything I am doing wrong or need to set other than X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I needed to create campaign first.

```
$result = $mgClient->post("$domain/campaigns", array(
        'name' => 'test campaign',
        'id'   => 'my_test_campaign'
    ));
```